# Least squares solution to two equations with two single common variable

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

could not find any information on the problem I face or even the name for this whatsoever.

I hvae $K$ equations

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}_1 \beta_1 + \mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{\gamma}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}_k \beta_k + \mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{\gamma}
$$

As you can see all of the equations share the same $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{\gamma}$. Also any of $\mathbf{X}_k$ and $\mathbf{X}_0$  might have a higher dimension than 1 (but the same number of rows).

I'd like to find a solution to this overdetermined system (i.e. find parameters $\mathbf{\beta_k}$ and $\mathbf{\gamma}$) that will minimize sum of squares of all of these equations. If not the common terms I'd simply use standard method for OLS for every equation separately.

Certainly, I could find some solution with brute force optimization but I wonder, is there any analytical solution?

I am not sure if the context is relevant here but I want to write an expectation-maximization algorithm for mixture of gaussian regressions where some of the terms are known to be the same among these regressions.

Comment: Are the bold variables $(y, X_1, .. , X_k, X_0)$ all column vectors?

Comment: y is a column vector, $X_1$, .., $X_k$ are matrices with the same dimension and $X_0$ is also a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let k=2 so we are working with just $y\ x_0\ x_1$ and $x_2$ 
The left-hand side becomes

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y^1\\
y^2\\
\vdots\\
y^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y^1\\
y^2\\
\vdots\\
y^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y^1\\
y^2\\
\vdots\\
y^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the right-hand side becomes $X \beta$ where $X$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0^1\\
x_0^2\\
\vdots\\
x_0^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^1\\
x_1^2\\
\vdots\\
x_1^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0^1\\
x_0^2\\
\vdots\\
x_0^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2^1\\
x_2^2\\
\vdots\\
x_2^n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and beta is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma\\
\beta_1\\
\beta_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then solve as usual (premultiply both sides by $X^T$ then premultiply by the inverse of $X^TX$ etc.)